# Which is the subject?

Tags: ellipsis, subjects

> I heard the high thin laugh again. "You're nobody, son. You don't
>   exist - can't you see that? The white folk tell everybody what to
>   **think** - except men like me. I tell them; that's my life, telling white folk how to think about the things I know about. Shocks you,
>   doesn't it? (Ralph Ellison, Invisible Man)

Which is the semantic subject of the verb think, the white folk or everybody?

Comment: A tells B [what B should think]. The subject of think is 'everybody except men like me'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject is the "main" part of a clause. The other part of a clause (the predicate) should be telling you something about the subject. In active voice, the subject of a verb will always be the thing that is *verbing*.

In this statement you have a nested clause, which seems to be what's causing you the confusion.

> **The white folk** are always telling everybody [what to think].

The verb *think* is not directly linked to the subject of the main clause (*white folk*). Rather all that follows is its predicate, and *to tell* is the verb tied to *white folk*. The bracketed section of the sentence is the nested clause.

So the verb *think* is in the nested (or subordinate) clause, of which *white folk* is no longer the subject. The *thinking* is being done by *everybody* in this sentence -- grammatically speaking, at least.

**The subject of the verb *think* is *everybody*.**